# Spring Cloud Stream @StreamListener Custom MappingJackson2MesageConverter

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, jackson-databind, spring-messaging

I have a custom `ObjectMapper` configured within my application which has custom modules for deserializing immutable types provided by Guava in Jackson.

My problem is that I cannot seem to override the `objectMapper` use by `@StreamListener` such that it deserializes my objects correctly.

Here is what I have tried:

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
    final MappingJackson2MessageConverter mappingJackson2MessageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2MessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return mappingJackson2MessageConverter;
}
```

The above snippet is in a class annotated with `@Configuration` and the `objectMapper` is defined in the class:

```
    public static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES))
        .registerModule(new GuavaModule());
```

Any ideas on what I may be missing?

- **Spring Boot:** 1.5.10.RELEASE
- **Spring Rabbit:** 1.7.6.RELEASE
- **Spring Cloud Stream:** 1.2.2.RELEASE
- **Spring Messaging:** 4.3.14.RELEASE

Comment: You are using older releases. Can you try upgrading to Spring Cloud Stream 2.0.x release (which requires Boot 2.0.x)?

Comment: @sobychacko, if I had that as an easy option, I would definitely do that.  However, I am trying to solve this for the current version stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out there was no issue with my configuration.  My custom `ObjectMapper` was being selected by the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`.  However, the message converter was not being selected, because the messages were being sent with the wrong content-type header.

Moral of the story, be careful with the Content-Type and make sure it matches the converter.